# React render to element by class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How i can render my component in few elements by class? I have one component, and i need show him in my page in differents tags, but with general logic

```
var FilterBox = React.createFactory(FilterBox),
                ToRender = document.getElementsByClassName('filter-box')
React.render(FilterBox(), ToRender);
```

html:

```
<div class="filter-box"></div>
...
...
<div class="filter-box"></div>
```

Comment: It would help if you added more detail, like an example of what you mean by "different tags". Also a more extensive code showing what you currently have working or what you have tried to do.

Answer (score -1):

you should be able to iterate over your classes and call `React.render` in each

```
for(var i;i < ToRender.length;i++{
  React.render(FilterBox(), ToRender[i])
}
```